# What is the "appropriate" way to aggregate different proportions?

Tags: mean, aggregation

I've found a lot of ways -- arithmetic mean, geometric mean, harmonic mean -- and I've invented things which have no name (and, likely, deserved none). At the end I just get a number and it's hard to tell if I have the *right* number.

Basically my situation is I have a variety of measurements of time spent in a certain pipeline. Depending on the inputs to that pipeline (size of data, basically), the total time spent, as well as the time spent in any particular stage, varies dramatically. Nevertheless, I want some kind of aggregate measurement for "the proportion of time spent in stage X."

For instance my measurements might look like:

1. 10s total, 1.5s in stage X
2. 150s total, 20s in stage X
3. 30s total, 10s in stage X
   etc.

And I want some kind of "average" "proportion of time spent in stage X."

The main properties I'd like to preserve are:

- The measurement is *sane* -- if the numbers are close together, the aggregate measurement is close to those numbers
- The measurement isn't dominated by "large" inputs -- for instance in the above sample, if I just did a ratio of arithmetic means, measurement 2 would dominate everything because it's so much larger.
- For any particular measurement, the sum of time across all stages is the total time; I'd like this to be true of the "averages" as well. That is, if the process is stage X, Y, and Z; then `averageProportion(X) + averageProportion(Y) + averageProportion(Z) == 1`

Comment: Your last property suggests to me that you should fit a Dirischlet distribution that describes the proportion of times for all stages, then take the mean of that.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want large inputs to have more influence? I would just use the sum of each of the stage times over the sum of the total times. So the average proportion for $X$ would be $(1.5 + 20 + 10)/(10+150 + 30)=0.1658$ Then your last property will be guaranteed.